# counting number of occurrences in multiple pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas

```
dg  se
29  10
37  22
3   13
15  7
42  20
31  23
26  17
7   1
36  19
5   7
21  5
37  13
37  6
2   24
```

In the dataframe above, I want to count the percentage of occurences in each column of values between 0 - 30, 30 - 40 and > 40; and also percentage of occurrences where both columns have values between 0 - 30 and 30 - 40. I was thinking of using pandas `hist`function but that does not do what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) for binning both columns:

```
bins = [0, 30, 40, np.inf]
labels = ['0-30','30-40','40+']
dg = pd.cut(df['dg'], bins=bins, labels = labels, include_lowest=True)
se = pd.cut(df['se'], bins=bins, labels = labels, include_lowest=True)
```

And then [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html):

```
dg_per = dg.value_counts(normalize=True)
print (dg_per)
0-30     0.571429
30-40    0.357143
40+      0.071429
Name: dg, dtype: float64

se_per = se.value_counts(normalize=True)
print (se_per)
0-30     1.0
40+      0.0
30-40    0.0
Name: se, dtype: float64
```

And for same values in both columns first filter:

```
both = (dg[dg == se])
print (both.value_counts(normalize=True))
0-30     1.0
40+      0.0
30-40    0.0
Name: dg, dtype: float64
```

Comment: thanks! in `both = (dg[dg == se])`, how can `0-30` have a value of 1.0? That would imply that both columns have all values between `0-30` (which is not the case)

Comment: @jezrael If I'm not wrong, that implies that whenever both columns belong to the same bin, it's always in the 0-30 range, which is true.

Comment: @user308827 - Mybe problem is need something else for `both` output, can you explin more?

Comment: @jezrael, for `both` output, we should consider those rows which are in the same bin.

Comment: OK, so filtering is what need, right? and because in `se` are only `0-30` values, get for `0-30` value`1`.